# 3G downloading a retina-only game?

Tags: iphone, display

If I try to download a game from the AppStore from an iPhone 3G, and the game says in the requirements that it only supports 3GS+, will the AppStore immediately disallow me the download or will it let me download nonetheless?

Comment: Also, you may want to download the app to one device, then transfer to another device (which, for some reason, won't support the type of downloading you can do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will complete the purchase request regardless. It just won't run on your device.

If you did make a purchase that doesn't run on your current device, you will have to contact the [iTunes team and request a refund](http://www.ehow.com/how_5590751_refund-itunes.html).

Comment: Is there a warning dialogue at least?

Comment: @Thilo No. It will download just like any other app. But when you run it, it will immediately close. This is a limitation of iOS. You can always send Apple feedback to include such a thing, and as they now actively support a range of different devices, that may well come in the future. But as it stands, there is no warning or system to prevent such occurrences from taking place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing the application from your device and it gives you a purchase option then it WILL let you buy it without further confirmation of device model.

It IS possible for a developer to hide an application from being purchased on specific device models. If you can still search for the application on your device they have not done that. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431825/adding-ipod-support-to-previously-iphone-only-app) on StackOverflow for technical proof that applications can be restricted to certain devices correctly.

This could mean that the developer wasn't aware of this capability, or that the 3GS+ requirement is just a recommendation, as they feel that the game runs too slowly, or has not been testing on an iPhone 3G.

In the end its up to you. Condsider trying a demo version of the game if available, or if you know a friend who has previously purchased the game for a higher spec iPhone trying their copy on your device temporarily.